# Advice respect an architecture PBX

Tags: asterisk, sip, pbx, rtp

i'm new on the world of PBX and network infrastructure.

I worked in a model and wanted to know how feasible it is to implement it in a production environment.

The requirement is to create a solution in the cloud to offer SME customers with our custom services, one of that is the VoIP service.

So I thought on this:

- Create a farm of VPS with Asterisk (one per client) each with his own port and RDP.
  range.
- Create rules in the Router to fowarding traffic from X port to
  specific private IP.

Here is a link to an image that i made on visio (i'm really sorry it's horrible, have compasion for me)

[Link to the image!](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2b5x15&s=5)

So what you think? It is possible to make?

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a few dozen of customers, you will find it expensive and difficult to maintain all those servers. FreeSWITCH supports multi-tenant scenarios, where you can have multiple subscriber domains and independent dialplan contexts. In general, I would advise to use FreeSWITCH instead of Asterisk for all green-field projects.